# Why cant I read document using its ID

Tags: node.js, api, express, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to read a single document using its ID from CosmosDb.

```
app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const dbResponse = await cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists({
            id: databaseId
        });
        let database = dbResponse.database;
    
        const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({id: containerId});
       
        var test = req.params;
        
        const docResponse = await container.item(test);
        const result = docResponse.read();
        console.log(result);
        
    } catch (error) {
        
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send("Error with database query: " + error.body);
        
    }

})
```

This is a get method that takes the id. I am using req.params to retrieve the ID and then using it to find the document within the database.
I am not sure why this is not working, I run this `localhost:3000/4040c` in postman against the GET method. Can someone please tell me why it's not working and what should I do to get the document using its Id?

---EDIT---
If I run this query how can I output its result? Every time I run this it says undefined

```
var test = req.params;

        const querySpec = {
            query: `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = "${test}"`
          };
        
        
        const docResponse = await container.item(querySpec);
        console.log(docResponse.result);
enter code here
enter code here
```

UPDATE
I am trying this now, I am hoping var test takes the id from the req.params property. Is my GET method correct? This gives me an error `TypeError: container.items.query(...).fetchAll is not a function` . I read online documentation, they have the same line as `const { resources: results } = await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();` . I don't know why mines not working.

```
app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const dbResponse = await cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists({
            id: databaseId
        });
        let database = dbResponse.database;
    
        const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({id: containerId});
        

        var test = req.params.id;


          const querySpec = {
            query: "SELECT * FROM Root r WHERE r.id = @id",
            parameters: [
              {
                name: "@id",
                value: "4040",
              }
            ]
          };

  const { resources: results } = await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
console.log(results);
```

Comment: If you need to read a single item you do not need to use a query. There are really good docs that provide examples for the JS SDK here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-samples

Comment: Mark...the problem here is that only id is used. To read a single document you need both id and partition key (as mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please tell me why it's not working and what should I do
> to get the document using its Id?

What you're trying to do is perform a `point read` and that requires you to specify both the item id and the partition key. Considering you're not specifying the partition key, SDK is searching for the document with the id you specified in `unknown` partition. This is why you're not able to read the document by simply specifying it's id.

If you want to fetch a document just by using id, you will have to execute a query (`Select * from Root r where r.id = 'id'`) and iterate over the resultset to get the item. However, please note that it will be a cross-partition query. You may get 1 result, more than 1 results (if document by same id exists in different partitions) or even 0 results.

**Update**

Here's the sample code to perform a query operation:

```
  const querySpec = {
    query: "SELECT * FROM Root r WHERE r.id = @id",
    parameters: [
      {
        name: "@id",
        value: "your-document-id"
      }
    ]
  };

  logStep("Query items in container '" + container.id + "'");
  const { resources: results } = await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();

  if (results.length == 0) {
    throw "No items found matching";
  } else if (results.length > 1) {
    throw "More than 1 item found matching";
  }

  const item = results[0];
```

---

For more samples, please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-samples.

Comment: let's say if I run a query, how can I output its result.

Comment: Updated my original post

Comment: What’s not working? Please edit your question and include that.

Comment: I would also suggest running your code with fixed id so that you know that your Cosmos DB code works.

Comment: I think I know my DB is working because I can get all the items. It's only when I need one item and I have to use its Id. It's only then it is not working.

Comment: Do a point read then using both id and partition key as that’s the right way to read a single document.

Comment: Is there documentation for the partition key, I don't know what that is. I Will work on this.